# Disable wordpress parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, parameters

I am currently using the 's' parameter for my pages.

Wordpress automatically makes it a search.

I want to disable the 's' parameter. I dont need the search function on my site.

Tried to find an answer or a direction to go into, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant write it yourself there is a [plugin for that](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-search/), it unsets all the `s` parameters and the sets a 404:

```
<?php
/**
 * Unsets all search-related variables in WP_Query object and sets the
 * request as a 404 if a search was attempted.
 *
 * @param object $obj A WP_Query object
 * @return null
 */
public static function parse_query( $obj ) {
    if ( $obj->is_search && $obj->is_main_query() ) {
        unset( $_GET['s'] );
        unset( $_POST['s'] );
        unset( $_REQUEST['s'] );
        unset( $obj->query['s'] );
        $obj->set( 's', '' );
        $obj->is_search = false;
        $obj->set_404();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, in what file would i put this?
Would it be in the template folder?

Comment: Download and Unzip [disable-search.zip](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/disable-search.1.4.zip) into the `/wp-content/plugins/` directory for your site (or install via the built-in WordPress plugin installer) Activate the plugin through the 'Plugins' admin menu in WordPress.